# Matrix to the nth exponent is it's own derivative. Coincidence or not?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
X & 0\\
1 & X\\
   \end{bmatrix} =
 \begin{bmatrix}
X & 0\\
1 & X\\
   \end{bmatrix}$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}
X & 0\\
1 & X\\
   \end{bmatrix}^2 = \begin{bmatrix}
X^2 & 0\\
2X & X^2\\
   \end{bmatrix}$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}
X & 0\\
1 & X\\
   \end{bmatrix}^3 =
\begin{bmatrix}
X^3 & 0\\
2X^2+X^2 & X^3\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
X & 0\\
1 & X\\
   \end{bmatrix}^n =
\begin{bmatrix}
X^n & 0\\
nX^{n-1} & X^n\\
   \end{bmatrix}^n$$
Here you can see that the this matrix on the n-th exponent is it's own derivative. Is there any explanation for this ?

$n = 1,2,3 \rightarrow\text{induction holds}$

$n \rightarrow n+1$
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
X & 0\\
1 & X\\
   \end{bmatrix}^{n+1} = \begin{bmatrix}
X & 0\\
1 & X\\
   \end{bmatrix}^n \begin{bmatrix}
X & 0\\
1 & X\\
   \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
X^n & 0\\
nX^{n-1} & X^n\\\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
X & 0\\
1 & X\\\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
X^{n+1} & 0\\
(n+1)X^n & X^{n+1}\\\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Notice your matrix looks like $XI + \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, for $I$ the identity matrix. Then if we write $\epsilon$ for the second matrix of that sum (which I'm too lazy to tex again), we see $\epsilon^2 = 0$. So $(XI + \epsilon)^2 = X^I + 2X\epsilon + \epsilon^2$. Now perhaps this notation is more suggestive. This $\epsilon$ matrix is acting as an infinitessimal, and so we're doing an informal sort of calculus

Comment: Yours is a duplicate of a lovely question I saw a while ago where I first learned this fact. Give me a second to find it. It goes into much greater depth! ^_^

Comment: Here it is: [Why does this matrix give the derivative of a function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1541800/why-does-this-matrix-give-the-derivative-of-a-function)

Comment: It works with $\epsilon$ upper triangular instead of lower triangular (as in your question), but you can see the exact same idea works

Comment: But the short answer is "no, this is not a coincidence!" ^_^